# Why doesn't the desugared "." functor syntax for lists work the same as []?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm reading Programming in Prolog (5th Edition), and in Chapter 3 the book introduces lists with this syntax:

> The empty list is written as `[]` ... The head and tail of a list are
>   components of the functor named ".", which is the dot (called the
>   period or full stop). Thus, the list consisting of one element "`a`"
>   is "`.(a,[])`", ...
>
> the list consisting of the atoms `a`, `b` and `c` is written `.(a,.(b,.(c,[])))`, ...

Then on the next page it introduces the square bracket notation as if it is a sugared equivalent to the previous syntax:

> As the dot notation is often awkward for writing complicated lists,
>   there is another syntax that can be used for writing lists in a Prolog
>   program. This *list notation* consists of the elements of the list
>   separated by commas, and the whole list is enclosed in square
>   brackets. For example, the above lists can be written in the list
>   notation as `[a]` and `[a,b,c]`.

The page after that introduces the vertical bar syntax `[X|Y]` for matching on lists' heads/tails.

Why is it then, if I write these facts:

```
a([1,2,3]).
b(.(1,.(2,.(3,[])))).
```

This works:

```
?- a([X|Y]).
X = 1,
Y = [2, 3].
```

But not this?

```
?- b([X|Y]).
ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `3' (an integer)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] throw(error(type_error(dict,3),_7636))
ERROR:    [9] '$dicts':'.'(3,[],_7676) at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/dicts.pl:46
ERROR:    [8] b([_7704|_7706]) at /home/abe/code/programming_in_prolog/ch03/.scratch.pl:2
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

Edit: this attempt doesn't work either:

```
?- b(.(X,Y)).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] throw(error(instantiation_error,_7856))
ERROR:    [9] '$dicts':'.'(_7886,_7888,_7890) at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/boot/dicts.pl:46
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ver.7, you should write this unwieldy syntax:

```erlang
?- [user].
|: b('[|]'(1,'[|]'(2,'[|]'(3,[])))).
|: ^D% user://1 compiled 0.01 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- b([X|Y]).
X = 1,
Y = [2, 3].
```

This because, in short, the dot notation has been 'coopted' to support dictionary accessors in functional notation, for instance

```erlang
?- write(_{a:1}.a).
1
true.
```

See [this doc](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-lists) for details.

The whole [section 5](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=extensions) of the manual is about SWI-prolog syntax changes WRT ISO prolog standard.

Answer (score 1):

To complement CapelliC's answer, in SWI-Prolog the `.` atom is replaced by `[|]` as listbox constructor:

```
?- [user].
|: b('[|]'(1,'[|]'(2,'[|]'(3,[])))).
|: % user://2 compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- b(X).
X = [1, 2, 3].

?- b([X|Y]).
X = 1,
Y = [2, 3].

?- b([X,Y|Z]).
X = 1,
Y = 2,
Z = [3].
```